# Use sql server convert() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I'm trying to execute a query from Sql Server but I have a column type datetime, in my query I'm trying to get all the results between two dates, but for this I need to convert the datetime column to date, my query works fine, the problem is when I'm trying to execute it from Laravel.

I get the following error message:

> Invalid column name 'CONVERT(DATE, DatetimeColumn)'

Here is my code:

```
$data =DB::table('Table_Name')
->select('C1', 'CONVERT(DATE, SaleDate) as DateSale', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10')
->whereBetween('CONVERT(DATE, SaleDate)', ["2018-06-10", "2018-08-10"])
->orderBy('SaleDate', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `selectRaw` instead of `select`:

```
->selectRaw('C1, CONVERT(DATE, SaleDate) as DateSale, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10)
```

Comment: Not sure about SQL server, but MySQL doesn't allow you to use where on an alias.

Comment: I think you right, needs to be `having` instead of `where` in order to use alias, thank you